list all file in a folder in Onedrive using MS Graph Api
Im using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{UserId}}/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/children
But it seem wrong some where when I try to put driverID and ID into the URL.
It returns the following error:
HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid

I tested with Postman and I see that it already has an accessToken for Authorization.
What can I do now?


Is your Drive ID correct? as this query https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/drives/DriveID/items/ItemID/children works for me

Verify your DriveID using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/drives

yeah it correct. I already can create folder, add file, delete file for the new folder.
I want it to list all my folder

here is my URL : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{UserId}}/drives/b!GyOFL43LxU6bhKtUp9NY5t0rvYgmmWtNgGqMEuN-jS1sZX1TLV87T5lDpH1_eQgU/items/017G2VK4E5KJTRUCSYBRCKTYUM6ZVEBTML/children

Yeah that query works for me:)

How are you generating the token?

I use this api https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/v2.0/token
and send with key-value grand_type =client_credentials client_id ={{ClientID}} client_secret = {{ClientSecret}} and scope =https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
